# PostgreSQL: Joining two tables by timestamp without double occurance

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm looking for a PostgreSQL statement to connect two databases, however an easy join doesn't do what i want. Given are two tables: One is logging an oven (based on temperature and maschine state logging), the other one is logging the products. Each product is assigned to exactly one oven run, so no double assignement of one product row should occur.

**oven**

```
oven_id | runstart         | runend           | max_temp 
1       | 06.04.2020 19:33 | 06.04.2020 21:03 | 100        A
1       | 06.04.2020 23:28 | 07.04.2020 00:58 | 102        B
1       | 07.04.2020 10:00 | 07.04.2020 11:30 | 98         C
...
```

**product**

```
oven_id | oven_run | product_ids | preprocessing    | postprocessing
1       | 11100    | [1,4,6]     | 06.04.2020 12:44 | 06.04.2020 21:29     1
1       | 11101    | [2,3,7]     | 06.04.2020 19:24 | 07.04.2020 08:12     2
1       | 11102    | [5,8,9]     | 07.04.2020 05:31 | 07.04.2020 19:05     3
...
```

My first approach:

```
select * 
from oven
left join product
    on oven.runstart>product.preprocessing and oven.runend<product.postprocessing and oven.oven_id=product.oven_id
```

However, in some specific situations (such as the example above), this query is not showing the desired result, cause I get four rows (for simplicity, rows are labeled with ABC and 123 in the example above): A-1, A-2, B-2 and C-3

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dBSGUE1nhvAkiZuGnL2nqs/3

The actual thing I am looking for is a 1:1 assignment (each oven run is exactly assigned to one product, no oven run or product is used twice), so each oven row should be assigned to one product row. Given the example shown above, from a logical point of view, the combination A-2 should be neglected, as otherways one product would be twice in the oven (product 2 has to be run B, as otherwise no products in run
 B).

Any idea how I can adjust the query to receive only three rows: A-1, B-2, C-3

Thanks for your support!

Comment: I get 3 rows, one with no match.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dBSGUE1nhvAkiZuGnL2nqs/1

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson You're right. There seems to be a display error using phyton/pandas. I will have a check on this later on. For now, I have taken other values for the two tables: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dBSGUE1nhvAkiZuGnL2nqs/3

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: You don't clearly describe the result, how output is a function of input. You just give fragments here & there about what it should or shouldn't be like or have in it. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Say what you expect to get & why you expect to get it in terms of how operators & expressions work. Please don't add "EDIT"s etc, just edit your post to the best possible presentation. Use text, not links/images, for text. [ask]

Comment: Please put everything needed to ask your question in the post itself, not just at a fiddle. PS Including desired output for minimal representative input. PS This is stll not clear & still doesn't give a specification or clearly describe your problem. No one could take this description & know what query would be OK. PS "logical point of view" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to match them perfectly, you don't have the necessary data for that.

F.ex. if you have the following setup (where time on the X axis):

```
<-- preprocessing 1 ---------------------------------- postprocessing 1 -->
   <-- preprocessing 2 -------------------------------- postprocessing 2 -->
      <-- runstart A --- runend A -->
                                      <-- runstart B -- runend B -->
```

You can't really pair **only** 1-A and 2-B. If you do that, that's just guessing. However if guessing is good enough for you, you can search for the oven-product pairs 1-by-1, f.ex. with this:

```
with recursive pairs(o, p) as (
  select * from (
    select oven, product
    from oven
    left join product
      on oven.oven_id = product.oven_id
      and tsrange(preprocessing, postprocessing) @> tsrange(runstart, runend)
    order by runstart
    limit 1
  ) as initial
  union all
  select * from (
    select oven, product
    from pairs, oven
    left join product
      on oven.oven_id = product.oven_id
      and tsrange(preprocessing, postprocessing) @> tsrange(runstart, runend)
    where (o) != oven -- use row-unique ID here, if you have
    and (o).runstart <= oven.runstart
    order by runstart
    limit 1
  ) as next
)
select (o).*, (p).*
from pairs
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3711YsHr3F5warVNaAB6LC/0

PS: this will only work with 1 `oven_id` though. If you need to gather these for every `oven_id` at the same time, you'll need to use some aggregation also (but that will make the query overly complicated, I'm not sure if it worth the effort at that point.)